# Format date in rails to Year-Month-Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 4.0, I need to return a date for the first of the current month in the following format:

`2014-01-01`

`Date.today.at_beginning_of_month` gives me this:

`Wed, 01 Jan 2014`

How can I format the date to the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.strftime # => "2014-01-01"
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.strftime("%F")
```

See: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime
for various other date and time formats.

> %F               => 2007-11-19                Calendar date (extended)